# How signals work on linux (c)?

Tags: c, linux, signals

What should i type in terminal to make it print "Hi" or "Bye" ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void catcher1(int signum)
{
    printf("/nHi");
    kill(getpid(),22);
}

void catch22(int signum)
{
    printf("\nBye\n");
    exit(0);
}

main()
{
    signal(SIGTERM, catcher1);
    signal(22, catch22);
    printf("\nLook & Listen\n");
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` ->`bg` ->  `ps` -> `kill -SIGTERM (the proper pid)` or `kill -22 (the proper pid)`, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/signals.htm)

"*Signals are software interrupts. They are used for inter-process communication in UNIX and UNIX-like operating systems such as Linux.
Signals have been in use since Bell Labs UNIX in the 1970s, and today are formally defined by the POSIX standard.
When a signal is sent to a process, the operating system interrupts the normal flow of the process execution and delivers the notification. If the process has previously registered a way to handle that particular signal, that routine is executed, otherwise the system executes the default signal handler.
Signals can be sent with the kill command.*"

Thus, signals are not stuff typed in the terminal but certain characters or commands input to send a signal.

Comment: Is it  signal(SIGTERM, catcher1); prototype or is it call function?

Comment: looks like it is calling a function inside the signal.h file.